# Image cannot load on HTML live preview when inserted command on CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning about creating a website utilizing HTML and CSS through a course on StackSkills. But following the tutorial videos on one of the steps where you have to upload a image, the image is not appearing in the background. Even though, I have the imaged saved in the img folder under resources. What might be causing the issue for the image to not display properly on the live preview as intended? Would really appreciate anyone's input.

[image]

I tried to apply the correct path of the image to the designated folder. But still no positive results.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Note that image paths should be relative to the location of the CSS file.

Comment: Could you upload the html and css file completely? There is not enough context here to see exactly what the problem is.